# Creating a textfile in a script sh

Tags: shell

I'm working on a lil' shell script to create a Venn diagramm for my internship. 
The first step is to extract a gene list from a \t table textfile and then build diagram with a python script.

But when executing this script in a terminal, I have a bad issue with the output file list_geneX.txt . It appear that some others and unknown characters are added next to the txt extension such as "list_gene1.txt" "list_gene2.txt", and my python script cant find the expected files.

I dont know how to fix this, and its quite strange because these files contain the expected content when open with a text editor.

Thx

PS:Sorry for that poor english/programming,Im a young bio-informatic student, but practice makes perfect:)

Here is the code

dont work as script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#launch ./make_Venn.sh DEonly_DESeqRes_MS.CD8naiv_MS.CD4naiv.tsv DEonly_DESeqRes_HV.CD8naiv_HV.CD4naiv.tsv
#
file1=$1
file2=$2
name1=${file1:16}
name2=${file2:16}
cat $file1 | awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'  | sed '1d' > list_gene1.txt
cat $file2 | awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'  | sed '1d' > list_gene2.txt
./venn.py $name1 list_gene1.txt $name2 list_gene2.txt
```

work when copy/pasted in a terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
file1="DEonly_DESeqRes_MS.CD8naiv_MS.CD4naiv.tsv"
file2="DEonly_DESeqRes_HV.CD8naiv_HV.CD4naiv.tsv"
name1=${file1:16}
name2=${file2:16}
cat DEonly_DESeqRes_MS.CD8naiv_MS.CD4naiv.tsv | sed '1d'  | awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'> list_gene1.txt
cat DEonly_DESeqRes_HV.CD8naiv_HV.CD4naiv.tsv | sed '1d'  | awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'> list_gene2.txt
./venn.py $name1 list_gene1.txt $name2 list_gene2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
name1=${file1:0:16}    #this will give you the first 16 characters


name1=${file1:16}      #your code was giving you character index 17 to end
```